# Motivation for contractions/extensions of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, soft-question, ideals

I am uncertain about the motivation for the contraction and extension of ideals. I understand the definition, and understand that the two operations respect certain properties, e.g. if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a ring homomorphism, then $\mathfrak{b}$ is a prime ideal of $B$ $\implies$ $\mathfrak{b}^c$ is a prime ideal of $A$, or that contracting and extending an ideal in $A$ is a projection.

Naturally I would expect such operations to also help gain more insight about the rings $A$ and $B$, or the ideals being contracted/extended. However, I haven't seen yet any examples of contractions/extensions giving any particular interesting insight.

The following quote from the Wikipedia page on ideals suggests that there is some non-trivial insight to be gained from studying contractions/extensions, at least for an algebraic number-theoretic setting:

> Remark: Let $K$ be a field extension of $L$, and let $B$ and $A$ be the rings of integers of $K$ and $L$, respectively. Then $B$ is an integral extension of $A$, and we let $f$ be the inclusion map from $A$ to $B$. The behaviour of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$ under extension is one of the central problems of algebraic number theory.

I have not yet studied algebraic number theory indepth, so I am missing the bigger picture of how studying extensions of prime ideals of $A$ is useful in this scenario. What I am hoping for is that the above quote is a specific instance of a more general ring-theoretic scenario, and if the corresponding idea behind it could be motivated.

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting insights about commutative algebra results for me is looking for their implications in Algebraic Geometry.

These notes from Andreas Gathmann (https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/en/commalg.php) have a whole chapter (9) dedicated to ring extensions, and the results *Lying Over* and *Going Up* are translated to problems about when a projection of a variety is well behaved or not. In these cases, you can really see how the contraction of a prime ideal is related with the problem of surjectivity of this projection, for example.